# How to call a variable from __init__ in same package (Python)

Tags: python, import

The case is like that, I have a package dir:

```
pkg
 |_____  __init__.py
 |_____  foo.py
```

The code in `__init__.py`:

```
param = 1

def get_param():
    return param

from .foo import *
```

And now I would like to call the param from `__init__.py` in `foo.py`, so my code is like that:

```
import pkg

new_param = pkg.get_param()
```

However, you can find that I call `foo.py` twice.

what is other method I can call the param from `__init__.py` in `foo.py`? It means `param` just like a global variable in package? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dont write `get_param()` in `__init__.py`**

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

so goal of `__init__.py`  is helps to to treat given directory as package like,

```
pkg
 |_____  __init__.py
 |_____  foo.py
```

it will helps you to call,

```
from pkg.foo import *
```

instead you can write it into another file under `pkg->param.py`

then call it as, `from pkg.param import get_param`

Comment: I see this kind of usage in Keras: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/__init__.py#L88

Comment: mostly __init__.py will use to setup config of the package.. like package path usage etc... so writing function inside wasn't preferable ... BTW __init__.py meant, prepend directory. in your case it is in the name of pkg